# How do I know if a piece of clothing can have a crew emblem added to it?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

As you know, in GTA V - Online there are Crews and each Crew can create it's own emblem. I think its quite cool that u can "place" the emblem on your shirt/coat/sweater - whatever top wear - on the front or on the back but it doesn't work for "every" (only top) wear. The menu point where I can "buy" the emblem and where I could choose a place where I would like to place the emblem is appearing only if it's possible.

The annoying thing is that I first **need** to buy the desired top to see if its possible to place the emblem. Now just wondering if there is something like a list that shows on which clothes we can put emblems or maybe I can read that information somewhere ingame. Didn't find out yet. Would save me some money :)

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Crew emblems can go on leather jackets and t-shirts, possibly more.

Comment: So far, information I can find online suggests you can put a crew emblem on any top except a vest or suit jacket, but some of it might be tied to your Crew RP, especially the leather jacket.

Answer (score 2):

Well since noone else has an answer, and im looking for a list too, ill just say that as far as ive seen in researching this is that you could only place your crew emblem on a "Crew T-Shirt" and on the hood of your car.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like crew emblems can be applied to any plain colored top that is not a suit jacket or a vest. So as long as the item of clothing you are looking at doesn't have stripes, and isn't a suit jacket or vest, you should be able to add your crew emblem to it. Do note that if the shirt already has a logo on it, you can't add a crew emblem there, but you can usually put it on the back of your shirt in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I know for sure that you can put it on track jackets and leather jackets (although the latter is determinant upon your Crew RP), but those are the only two types of jackets I've been able to place them on. Also, Unionhawk is correct. All non-jacket tops can have a Crew logo except vests, polo shirts, and those oddly patterned (plaid and such) button down tops.